# Is it possible to compile a typescript project in a typescript bundle?

Tags: typescript, webpack, lua, tsc, typescript-to-lua

This is a trivial question: I'm using a tool that compiles [typescript to Lua](https://typescripttolua.github.io/). However, this tool doesn't support [node_module resolution yet](https://github.com/TypeScriptToLua/TypeScriptToLua/pull/1011).

But as a workaround, I could build the Lua sources in 2 steps:

1. bundle my sources and all the dependencies in a single **.ts** file
2. use TypeScriptToLua to generate the Lua file from the bundled file

Webpack and TSC are only able to generate JS as far as I know and google doesn't help

Therefore, my question is: **is there any possibility to pack TS files into a TS bundle?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the typescript to lua tool require everything to have types to do its job? If not, you can create a JS bundle and then rename the file to .ts. Boom! you now have a typescript bundle. Everything's an implicit `any`, but it's still typescript.

Comment: I'm gonna try it. Stay tuned :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work because the typescriptToLua needs the types to apply the correct conversion rules